# Sequences and real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, number-systems

Based on the answers so far I restate the question: on p. 63 of his volume on Analysis (http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~okra/2011-MathIV/Zorich1.pdf), Zorich says: “We now answer the question whether some real number $x \in \mathbb{R}$ corresponds to every symbol $\alpha_{p}...\alpha_{0}...$ The answer turns out to be negative.” This seems to mean that there are more sequences of the form $r_n = \alpha_pq^p + \dots + \alpha_{p-n}q^{p-n}$ than real numbers. On the same pages Zorich names those additional sequences: those in which “all these numbers [$\alpha_{p-j}$] from some point on are equal to $q-1$”. What exactly does this mean? Are sequences like 3.999 (with $q=10$) deficient in some sense?

(The old question: One way of dealing with a decimal like $0.\bar{9}$ is simply to equate it with 1, but there is a notion that, if taken at face value, these decimals lead to contradictions and do not approximate real numbers as they should. There is a proof of this fact in Zorich’s volume on analysis, of which I totally fail to understand two critical steps (starting with the third, unnumbered, inequality on page 64 here: http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~okra/2011-MathIV/Zorich1.pdf), but I would be totally happy to have a rigorous proof of any kind.)

Comment: It's not that sequences that end with an infinity of trailing $q-1$ is contradictory or meaningless. It's just that if you want a one to one correspondence between the positive numbers and sequences of the form $\alpha_p\dots\alpha_0\dots$, you'll need to choose between sequences with an infinity of trailing $0$s or sequences with an infinity of trailing $9$s. We just choose the former because it's simpler.

Comment: @Farnight, Zorich says, “We remark that by virtue of the algorithm just described for obtaining the numbers alpha_{p-n} E {0, 1, ..., q-1} successively, **it cannot happen** that all these numbers from some point on are equal to q-1” (p. 63). Then he proceeds to show that such sequence would contradict the lemma, that for a fixed q for each x we can find an integer p satisfying q^p <= x < q^{p+1}.

Comment: It cannot happen because the algorithm he's using doesn't allow it. For instance if you use his algorithm to get the decimal expansion of $1.2$, it would give you $1\ 2\ 0\ 0\dots$, because that's what the algorithm does. But $1\ 1\ 9\ 9\dots$ is a valid decimal expansion as well.

Comment: @Farnight, thanks! That exactly what will happen in practice, but Zorich gives a proof that this is impossible, which I cannot fully understand. And also if the number in question is, for instance, 1.99999, Zorich’s approx. will give me 1.99999, and that is stated to be wrong, since it ends with 9999. What am I missing? He doesn’t even say that this sequence of 9’s should be infinite.

Comment: I believe his algorithm should give you $1\ 9\ 9\ 9\ 9\ 9\ 0\ 0\ 0\dots$. So the sequence doesn't end with trailing $9$s.

Answer (score 3):

1) there is no special need to deal with 0.999... any differently than any other decimal expansion.

2) Nobody 'simply equates' 0.999.... with 1. The two numbers are precisely equal following the meaning of what a decimal expansion is.

3) .... but there is a notion - which notion???

4) these decimal lead to contradictions - which contradictions?

5) no decimal expansion is an approximation of a real number. Instead it is precisely a real number.

6) I can't quite understand what you think is being proven on page 64.

7) you would be happy with a rigorous proof of what exactly?

Comment: Zorich says: ‘...we construct better and better approximations from below and from above to the number x using the special sequence (2.7)’. His special sequence is, if I get it right, a general form of expansion, if q = 10, it is the decimal expansion. For some reason we cannot use q-1 (9, for instance) as repeated factors in the final part of this sequence.

Answer (score 0):

**answer to version 2 of question**

This means that one defines an [equivalence class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class) of sequences which **effectively** (by the rules of arithmetic and infinitude) represent **exactly the same number**:

examples:

the sequence $0.123_{10}$ and the sequence $0.12299999.._{10}$ and so on. Due the the **infinite**  amount of digits equal $9$ and the number base $10$ these by the rules of arithmewtic, **represent exactly rhe same number** so one defines an equivalence class of these sequences and uses a representative of this class to define the representation of the number (anyone representative in the class will do, i.e both $0.123_{10}$ and $0.12299999.._{10}$ refer to the same number and they belong to the same equivalence class)

Comment: Thanks! That far I understand, however. The problem is, Zorich states that sequences that end with 9999 are in some sense contradictory, and I would like know what exactly he means by this, but I cannot understand his chain of arguments.

Comment: @DmitryNikolayev, hmm i dont think i can help there, since i would have to read the book very carefuly and do not have the time at this point, hope a better answer comes along. In any case this answer holds for at least part of the question